# Why couldn't I submit changes to a question?

Tags: support, editing

I tried to edit the question ["Do: Experience with the journal"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/do-experience-with-the-journal) to be of a more a question and answer format, following some of the other changes I've seen on the site.  I changed the question to "How does the Journal in Do: Pilgrims of the Flying Temple affect play of the game?" but I couldn't submit it, because I didn't make an appropriate number of changes to the body of the question, i.e "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?".  The edit was more than 6 characters; they just happened to fall in the title.  Is this really not an acceptable edit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edit requirement of 6 characters is *only* on edits to the question body. As such, if you want to modify the title, but don't have at least 6 characters of changes to the question body, simply make sure you make 0 changes to the question body.

Same goes for tags, by the way - those can be done without any restriction. The only issue is touching the body - essentially, it blocks edits of 1-5 characters. If your edit is 0 characters then you're in the clear.

Comment: Thanks!  That did it!  I must have done something in the body without realizing it.